# Centering text vertically inside array

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays

I want to have tikzpictures next to each other (horizontally) with an equal sign between them. I'm using an array environment. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[math]{cellspace}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ccc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

& \text{some text} & 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{array}
\]


\end{document}
```

This produces [image]

How can I make the "some text" vertically centered between the lines? I've tried a lot of solutions around here and none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple option is to use the `m` column type. The only limitation of this method is that you have to choose a wise value for the column widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{m{4cm} c m{4cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

& \text{some text} & 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use the `\vcenter` macro in mathmode.  Note that `\hbox` is used to create a horizontal box for the equation, which is then vertically centered with `\vcenter`.

```
\[
\begin{array}{c c c}

\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
}}

& \text{some text} & 

\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
}}

\end{array}
\]
```

[image]